# I can't load cordova plugins in ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Today, I took over a project based on ionic v1 from previous developer.

but when run **ionic serve** command, I am getting a lot of issues.

First of all, I can't load cordova plugins.

I have already plugin folder which has a lot of plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of plugins used in the project by using the command

```
gulp --cordova 'plugins ls'
           or
ionic cordova plugin ls
```

If you have plugins like phonebook contacts or sqlite then it won't run in your browser you have to run the application in real device or emulator.Check the [cordova plugins list](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html).

Comment: I chcked just. but all of plugins is listed by the command above that you want to run. I think that it's not a matter. what's next solution?

Comment: @Eric if u have plugins which will run only in mobile devices means then there is no use of using ionic serve. It won't  run in browser